# Getting "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream." while making API call to UPS tracking Rest service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, ups

I am implementing UPS tracking API in my asp.net mvc 5 application. I created below method.

```
public virtual Core.UPSTrackingResponse.UPSTrackingResponse TrackUPS(string trackingNumber)
{
    Core.UPSTrackingRequest.UPSTrackingRequest requestModal = new Core.UPSTrackingRequest.UPSTrackingRequest();
    requestModal.UPSSecurity.ServiceAccessToken.AccessLicenseNumber = UPSAccessKey;
    requestModal.UPSSecurity.UsernameToken.Username = UPSUserId;
    requestModal.UPSSecurity.UsernameToken.Password = UPSPassword;
    requestModal.TrackRequest.InquiryNumber = trackingNumber;
    requestModal.TrackRequest.Request.RequestOption = "1";
    requestModal.TrackRequest.Request.TransactionReference.CustomerContext = trackingNumber + " tracking context";

    string Data = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(requestModal);
    string response = "";
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UPSTrackingURL); // https://wwwcie.ups.com/rest/Track
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.KeepAlive = false;
    request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

    request.ContentType = @"application/json";
    request.ContentLength = Data.Length;

    StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
    requestWriter.Write(Data);
    requestWriter.Close();

    try
    {
        WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
        Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
        response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Out.WriteLine(response);
        responseReader.Close();
        Nop.Core.UPSTrackingResponse.UPSTrackingResponse ResponseModal =
            new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Nop.Core.UPSTrackingResponse.UPSTrackingResponse>(response);
        return ResponseModal;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This is working fine when i call it from my local machine. but when i deployed my application on AWS server, it keeps giving me below exception. What could be the reason, I'm stuck now.

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream.
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at Nop.Services.Shipping.ShippingService.TrackUPS(String trackingNumber)
   at Nop.Web.Controllers.OrderController.PrepareShipmentDetailsModel(Shipment shipment)
   at Nop.Web.Controllers.OrderController.ShipmentDetails(Int32 shipmentId)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: What .NET framework version is installed on that AWS server and your local machine?

Comment: you might need a certificate authentication

Comment: is it possible that the access key you are using is only valid for your local dev machine (localhost:***) but it is deployed to your server then the domain changes so the access key is not valid for that requesting client.

Comment: @Evk: Both local & server has .net 4.5.2 framework installed.

Comment: @Gurpreet: No, there is nothing like separate keys for local or server.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Did you ever fix this? I'm having the same issue but on a Windows server

Comment: @LewsTherin Yes i fixed it, actually i was using windows 2016 data center and some modules were missing in that windows edition. When I installed windows 2016 with IIS, everything starts working.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi Probably a stretch but do you know what modules were missing?

Answer (score 14):

Try adding this somewhere in the code, prior to making the call to the webservice:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
                    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                    | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: This fixed it for me

Comment: this is working in my local IIS only, when deployed over AWS, it does not work,

Answer (score 2):

If you have .NET 4.0 or .NET 3.5 answer of Alex K will not help as is.
Best way to solve it is **upgrade .NET**.

If you can't upgrade:
For **.Net 4.0** use following code:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

> There is also a registry hack which forces 4.5 to use TLS 1.2 by
>   default without enforcing it programmatically.

For **.NET 3.5**:

> There is a recent patch available for .NET 3.5 which is enabling
>   TLS1.2 support.

For more details see source here:
https://blogs.perficient.com/2016/04/28/tsl-1-2-and-net-support/